# Ubuntu 19.04 as LDAP client

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to switch our PC from Debian 8 to Ubuntu. The user accounts are on a server and managed via LDAP. But somehow I have problems configuring OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 19.04.

For a short history: I started a few days back on 18.10. and used [this](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-16-04-lts-as-ldap-client/) manual to set it up. But after making the changes to pam I ran into [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/1817897) bug, so the GUI was not working anymore. But logging in to an account on the server worked. In the search for a solution with gdm3, I tried LightDM and lxdm. In the former I couldn't find an "add user" button to log-in to an account not known yet until after trying lxdm. lxdm worked great, but is way too ugly. In the process of getting rid of lxdm I seem to have removed too much so yesterday I made a fresh start and upgraded to 19.04 before doing anything else after I found out that the bug was fixed. But now, on 19.04 I just can't manage to get the connection to work. And I have no clue where the problem is.

I even copied the necessary files from Debian (installation on a different SSD, so it's still available) and tried to include the changes like I did on 18.10, but for some reason, it's not working. I can get to the various servers we have via ssh so that isn't a problem. I didn't try the neccessary auth server since I would need to copy my public key, but when the other servers are available so is the auth is too. And a connection from windows isn't a problem, so it also can't be a problem with the server or connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Somehow I must have forgotten to remove the i in ldapi in the setup process. Our server doesn't speek ldapi